# nodejs throws error while calling createServer

Tags: node.js

I actually just repeated the code from a book but it wont work for some reason. Here is the code it self. It is pretty simple

```
var express = require('express')

var app = express.createServer();


app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send('Welcome')
})

app.listen(8000)
```

when i install express. I get this screen and I assume everything is ok

```
C:\>npm install express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/type-is
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-static
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/path-to-regexp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/merge-descriptors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/type-is
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-static
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/path-to-regexp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/merge-descriptors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
express@4.2.0 node_modules\express
├── parseurl@1.0.1
├── cookie@0.1.2
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
├── escape-html@1.0.1
├── cookie-signature@1.0.3
├── debug@0.8.1
├── range-parser@1.0.0
├── fresh@0.2.2
├── qs@0.6.6
├── methods@1.0.0
├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
├── serve-static@1.1.0
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.2
├── send@0.3.0 (debug@0.8.0, mime@1.2.11)
├── type-is@1.1.0 (mime@1.2.11)
└── accepts@1.0.1 (negotiator@0.4.3, mime@1.2.11)
```

When I try to run it. I get the error. It seems like createServer is throwing the error
As it is not defined or something

```
   C:\Users\User\Dropbox\Personal Documents\Staj node\expresstry>node expresstry.js


C:\Users\Sinan\Dropbox\Personal Documents\Staj node\expresstry\expresstry.js:7
var app = express.createServer();
              ^
TypeError: Object function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, proto);
  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype);

  app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
  app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
  app.init();
  return app;
} has no method 'createServer'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sinan\Dropbox\Personal Documents\Staj node\t
 witter\twitterbuild.js:7:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
       at startup (node.js:119:16)
        at node.js:906:3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In latest version it is simply:

```
var app = express();
```

So your code would be:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Welcome');
});

app.listen(8000);
```

[Source](https://github.com/visionmedia/express)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I should have checked the documentation in express website, It is my bad

Comment: @sinanspd not your fault. I had same issue just few weeks ago while trying to follow a post on creaing blog in node.js. This technology is so rapidly moving, that most context gets instantly outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Your book is based on an old version of `express`.  I would suggest looking for updated code samples.  If there are none, however, you can install an old version of express with

```
npm install express@2.0.0
```

If the book specifies a version of `express`, use that instead of `2.0.0` - I put that in because I know that version has `createServer`.

Note that this may be unstable (it wants to run on node `0.4`-`0.5`, which are way older than what you are probably running).  You would be better off finding updated code samples or using different material.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right, finding more upto date samples would be better and easier =)